# SEQUELIZE and node JS :primary key increases when a query fails

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

In Express and SEQUELIZE, when I execute a query and it fails for a reason and re execute another query to the same table the primary key increases by 2 not on, actually it increases by 1 for every failed query.

If query no 2 fails and query no 3 inserted the id of no 3 is 3 not 2!!.

Looks like it calculates the id of the failed queries.

Here is my code :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define("customer", {
        customer_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,

        },
        first_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notNull: {
                  msg: 'Please enter your first name'
                }
              }

        },
        last_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notNull: {
                  msg: 'Please enter your last name'
                }
              }
        },
        picture: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
           
        },
        phone_number: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: {
                arg: true,
                msg: 'This phone number is already taken.'
            },
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notNull: {
                  msg: 'Please enter your phone number'
                },
              }
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notNull: {
                  msg: 'Please enter your password'
                }
              }
        },
        birthdate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notNull: {
                  msg: 'Please enter your birth date'
                }
              }
        },
     
    },
     {timestamps: true},)
}
```

and the controller :

```
const Customer = db.customers;




const createCustomer = (req, res)=>{


    const {first_name, last_name, picture, phone_number, password, birthdate} = req.body;

    Customer.create({
        first_name,
        last_name,
        picture,
        phone_number,
        password,
        birthdate
    }).then((data)=>{

       res.send({data});

    }).catch(({errors})=>{
      

       return res.send(errors[0].message);
    });

 


}

module.exports = {createCustomer};
```

And here is a pic for the database(postgresql):

Look at the gaps!!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83350/prevent-primary-key-increment-when-an-insert-statement-fails-in-postgresql

Comment: The sequence works regardless either your query is succeeded or failed. Usually it should bother you at all either PK values have gaps or not. What's your concern?

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, well, the primary key as an integer has a maximum value right?, when it increases the primary key when it fails, the primary key will reach a number it can not exceed, and at that point you have gaps and values you have lost , for example PK holds only 10 users, and because of the failed queries you got this result : 1 user, 4 user, 9 user 10 user, in this case you can store 10 users but you got 4, as the PK can not be increased anymore, please correct me if I am wrong, and thanks.

Comment: Comparing to the maximum value (i.e. 2147483647) such gaps are like nothing significant. If you are that concerned about a PK value will be out of range soon than change the data type and use UUID value instead.